# W3WP Process at 100% Utilization

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, asp.net

We're seeing an issue on our production servers where the processor is constantly at 100% utilization (between 2 or 3 w3wp processes). The weird thing is that there are almost no requests to the server, and the application associated with the offending processes is still performing well. By looking at IISPeek, almost nothing is happening on the server, so I'm not sure what else to check. Has anyone run into something like this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using DebugDiag to monitor what's going on?  Otherwise, I'd suggest taking a process dump (eg using procdump) and examining it in WinDBG.

Comment: I used this tool (http://samsaffron.com/archive/2009/11/11/Diagnosing+runaway+CPU+in+a+Net+production+application), and see 'Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SetEvent' at the top, but that doesn't really give me any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a process dump and then use either Windbg or Visual Studio to analyse the dump and figure out what the process is doing. Here's a [guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892277).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was related to sending an email from .NET 2.0. We set ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1, which resulted in the connection staying open and consuming CPU in the background.

EDIT: After a little more research, this was actually our exact issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930236/net-best-method-to-send-email-system-net-mail-has-issues